# Why is the answer of laplace of $1 * t^2$ not equal to that you would get from convolution theorem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, convolution

So I know that
$$L(t^2) = \frac{2}{s^3}$$
but why is is that, if we use the convolution theorem for $1 \ast t^2$, we get
$$L(1*t^2) = \frac{1}{s}*\frac{2}{s^3}$$

Isn't $1 \ast t^2$ equal to $t^2$? Or am I missing something in the definition?
Sorry if it's a dumb question but I just really can't seem to understand.

(edit: corrected the fraction)

(edit: sorry about that, I just realized I definitely didn't have a good grasp on the definition!)

Comment: $1 \ast t^2$ is not equal to $t^2$! If you write down what the convolution actually is you'll get $\frac{t^3}{3}$. On the other side you'll get $\frac{1}{s} \cdot \frac{2}{s^3} = \frac{2}{s^4}$ (you wrote $s^2$ here, and you want the ordinary product here, not the convolution product) which is in fact the Laplace transform of $\frac{t^3}{3}$.

Comment: And this is precisely the reason why I encourage people to avoid using "$*$" for multiplcation (except of course when typing into software like Python.)

Comment: Yes, you're missing the definition of a convolution. Why do you guys hate definitions with that holy passion?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathcal {L}(1*t^2) = \mathcal {L} (1) \mathcal {L}(t^2)=\frac{1}{s}\times \dfrac {2!}{s^3}=\dfrac 2 {s^4}$$
Note that the convolution theorem gives us :
$$f(t)=1 *t^2 =\int^t_0 1 \times \tau ^2 d\tau$$
$$f(t)=\dfrac {\tau ^3}3 \bigg |_0^t=\dfrac {t^3}3$$
$$\mathcal {L}(f(t))=\dfrac 13 \dfrac {3!}{s^4}=\dfrac 2 {s^4}$$